# SQL Server Cursor Loop Alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursors

I have employee hours log data. Now I have to flag all the records where an employee logs the same hours for the same tasks on the consecutive work days (Sat/Sun weekend).

Let me explain my problem with following example

I have employee hour log table say EMP_HOUR_LOG:

```
ROW EMP_NO  TASK    DATE        HOURS   FLAG
1   1000    T1  2015-01-01  8   0
2   1000    T1  2015-01-02  8   0
3   1000    T1  2015-01-05  8   0
4   1000    T1  2015-01-06  2   0
5   1000    T2  2015-01-01  4   0
6   1000    T2  2015-01-02  3   0
7   1000    T3  2015-01-09  5   0
8   1000    T3  2015-01-12  5   0
9   1000    T3  2015-01-13  3   0
10  1001    T1  2015-01-14  3   0
11  1001    T1  2015-01-15  3   0
```

In the above sample dataset I have to update FLAG to 1 for row number 1, 2, 3, 10 and 11, as these records are entries where hours entered by a same employee for the same task on consecutive days is same.

I have already implemented this using cursors as I couldn't think of any alternative to looping through the data record by record.

Please let me know if anyone here can suggest any better way to implement the same by avoiding cursor loops or loops in general.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain why "3" would have a flag of 1, but not "7" and "8"?  Do you have a calendar table that describes which days are work days and not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably also rows 7 and 8 should have flag = 1.
This is the query, but I think the problem has to be handled during the insert:

```sql
update e set e.FLAG = 1 
from [dbo].[EMP_HOUR_LOG] e
where exists
(
    select * from [dbo].[EMP_HOUR_LOG] e1 
    where e1.[TASK] = e.[TASK] 
    and e1.[EMP_NO] = e.[EMP_NO]
    and e1.[HOURS] = e.[HOURS]
    and e1.[DATE] in 
        (
        --Next work day
        dateadd(dd, case when DATENAME(dw,e.[DATE]) = 'Friday' then 3 else 1 end, e.[DATE]), 
        --Previous work day
        dateadd(dd, case when DATENAME(dw,e.[DATE]) = 'Monday' then -3 else -1 end, e.[DATE])
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would solve the problem slightly differently. If you have the ability. This calculation is much easier to solve upfront. So instead of querying the whole problem-set you could isolate it when you insert the new record. Basically set the flag when you add a new record and update any records that sit either side (date wise) this has the advantage of always having your data in the correct state and it is less resource intensive as you do not need to consider every record in order to derive the flag value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly:
Same Employee, same task, with same amount of hours input one day after another (consecutive - weekends excluded).

But your described logic will pick also rows: 7 and 8

```
7   1000    T3  2015-01-09  5   0
8   1000    T3  2015-01-12  5   0
```

It is same employee `1000` same task `T3` same amount of hours `5` and `2015-01-09` is Friday and `2015-01-12` is monday so days are consecutive (weekends excluded)

---

Considering that I got it right here is MS SQL 2008 implementation:

```
WITH EHT AS (
SELECT [ROW]
      ,[EMP_NO]
      ,[TASK]
      ,[DATE]
      ,[HOURS]
      ,DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) AS DayWeek /* Sunday = 1 */
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP_NO],[TASK] ORDER BY [DATE]) AS DT_RNK
FROM [EMP_HOUR_LOG]
)

SELECT 
 A1.*
,A2.[DATE] AS Next_Date
,A3.[DATE] AS Previous_Date
,CASE /* for Next Date logic*/
     WHEN A2.DayWeek<>2 /*Tuesday to Friday*/
      AND DATEDIFF(DD, A1.[DATE], A2.[DATE]) = 1
     THEN 1
     WHEN  A2.DayWeek=2 /*Monday*/
      AND DATEDIFF(DD, A1.[DATE], A2.[DATE]) = 3 /* 3 days from Friday to Monday*/
     Then 1
     /* for Previous Date logic*/
     WHEN A2.[DATE] IS NULL 
      AND A3.DayWeek=6 /* Friday */
      AND DATEDIFF(DD, A3.[DATE], A1.[DATE]) = 3 /* 3 days from Friday to Monday*/
     THEN 1
     WHEN A2.[DATE] IS NULL 
      AND A3.DayWeek<>6 /* Mon to Thur */
      AND DATEDIFF(DD, A3.[DATE], A1.[DATE]) = 1 
     Then 1
     ELSE 0 END
 AS FLAG
FROM EHT AS A1
LEFT JOIN EHT AS A2
        ON (A1.[EMP_NO]=A2.[EMP_NO]
        AND A1.[TASK]=A2.[TASK]
        AND A1.[HOURS]=A2.[HOURS]
        AND A1.DT_RNK=A2.DT_RNK-1)
LEFT JOIN EHT AS A3
        ON (A1.[EMP_NO]=A3.[EMP_NO]
        AND A1.[TASK]=A3.[TASK]
        AND A1.[HOURS]=A3.[HOURS]
        AND A1.DT_RNK=A3.DT_RNK+1)
```

Firstly creating temp table EHT with Weekday function to identify if a day is saturday or sunday (7,1).
Adding Order number (Rwo_number function ) from 1...n which is reset on Employe, task and ordering dates from lowest to highest.

Then in second step Left joining EHT table to itself. With Emp, Task and hour columns (to exclude all case when emp, task and hours did not match)
+ shifting second table back by 1 Order num (`A1.DT_RNK=A2.DT_RNK-1`). With that I am able to identify Next data in series.

However Last date in series does not have Next date, because it is last. And I need to identify series from from beginning to the last item. Thus I am Left joining the table again but this time, shifting table forward by 1 order num (`A1.DT_RNK=A2.DT_RNK+1`) to identify Previous Date in a series.

Now the logic is just counting number of days between Date and Next date or Date and Previous date, if it is equal to 1, then they are consecutive. For Monday dates it have to be 3. Similarly when taking into account last entry in serie, which does not have next date, we need to check previous date if it is friday then it have to be also equal to 3.

PRobably there is simpler solution. But this is working. Still as  Gordon Linoff  mentioned above, you did not include into FLAG = 1  rows 7 and 8. My logic include them because it is from friday to monday consecutive dates. Maybe you are taking into account some other holidays.

Result details:
[image]